# How can I use a VirtualBox Ubuntu Server as a server?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I don't have access to a Linux server at the moment, and I'd like to temporarily use a virtualised Ubuntu server running on VirtualBox. I've installed it OK, but am not sure what network settings to use. Just to be clear: I want to initiate connections from my Windows desktop to a virtualised Ubuntu server running in VirtualBox (on the Windows box).

TIA

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are saying you are running Ubuntu Server on Virtual Box on the same machine you want to access it on, the most efficient way would be to change the VM's settings for the network adapter to be "attached to" the host-only adapter. Then access it by IP address as normal.

If you want to access it over the network anyway, change your settings again, but this time attach it to the Bridged Adapter. Access it by IP like normal.

Comment: Many thanks, took the bridged adapter route and it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

You have to Enable the Network Adapter.

It depends if you only plan to access it from your windows box you can set a Host-only adapter, or you can use a Bridged-Adapter if you want to be able to access it from other computers.